# Spring Boot Kafka Batch DefaultErrorHandler addNotRetryableExceptions?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

In Spring boot kafka batch consumer, I want to skip non retryable exceptions.

I've added an exception to the `DefaultErrorHandler.addNotRetryableExceptions`, if that exception is thrown. I was expecting it to go to the `ConsumerRecordRecoverer` and not be retired.

In my test, it will eventually go to `ConsumerRecordRecoverer` but only after it has been retried n times.

Does `DefaultErrorHandler.addNotRetryableExceptions` work in batch mode? Maybe I misread the spring kafka documentation.

My example test code, this is using *spring-kafka:2.9.2*

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoKafkaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoKafkaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(){
        return new CommandLineRunner() {
            @Autowired KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> kafkaTemplate;
            @Override
            public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
                kafkaTemplate.send("topic1", "hello");
                kafkaTemplate.send("topic1", "foo");
                kafkaTemplate.send("topic1", "derp");
                kafkaTemplate.send("topic1", "cheese");
                kafkaTemplate.send("topic1", "bar");
            }
        };
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "myId", topics = "topic1")
    public void listen(List<String> in) {
        System.out.println("----------------");
        in.forEach(str -> {
            System.out.println(str);
            if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("cheese")) throw new NullPointerException("cheese not allowed");
        });

        System.out.println("----------------");
    }

    class MyConsumerRecordRecoverer implements ConsumerRecordRecoverer{

        @Override
        public void accept(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord, Exception e) {
            System.out.println(consumerRecord.toString());
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableKafka
    class KafkaConfig{
        @Bean
        NewTopic topic(){
            return TopicBuilder.name("topic1")
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String>
        kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory) {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory =
                    new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
            factory.setBatchListener(true);
            factory.setCommonErrorHandler(commonErrorHandler());
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory() {
            return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProps());
        }

        private Map<String, Object> consumerProps() {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerDeserializer.class);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, "5000");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, "1000");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "2");
            return props;
        }

        @Bean
        public CommonErrorHandler commonErrorHandler() {
            DefaultErrorHandler defaultErrorHandler = 
                    new DefaultErrorHandler(myConsumerRecordRecoverer(), new FixedBackOff(2000,3));
            defaultErrorHandler.addNotRetryableExceptions(NullPointerException.class);
            return defaultErrorHandler;
        }

        @Bean
        public MyConsumerRecordRecoverer myConsumerRecordRecoverer(){
            return new MyConsumerRecordRecoverer();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works exactly as expected...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So74151506Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So74151506Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so74151506", topics = "so74151506")
    void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so74151506").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so74151506", "test");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    CommonErrorHandler eh() {
        DefaultErrorHandler eh = new DefaultErrorHandler((rec, ex) -> System.out.println("In recoverer"),
                new FixedBackOff(1000, 4));
        eh.addNotRetryableExceptions(NullPointerException.class);
        return eh;
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

```
test
In recoverer
```

If you can't figure out what's wrong, post a minimal, complete, reproducible example someplace so we can see what you are doing wrong.

**EDIT**

There is a bug in the `FallbackBatchErrorHandler`.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2459

However, with a batch listener, it is better to wrap the exception in a `BatchListenerFailedException`, telling the framework which record in the batch caused the failure, so that just that one will be retried and/or recovered.

Otherwise the entire batch is retried and sent to the recoverer.

This works as expected in your example:

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "so74151506", topics = "so74151506")
void listen(List<String> in) {
    for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); i++) {
        String str = in.get(i);
        System.out.println(str);
        if ("bar".equalsIgnoreCase(str)) {
            throw new BatchListenerFailedException("Listener Failed", new NullPointerException(), i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gary-Russel for your response. I think there are two differences between my example and yours:

`* I have listener type as Batch in the application.yaml
* The listen method takes a List<String> are input.`

I  have taken your example and altered it with the above changes, reproducible example --> https://github.com/jd1289/So74151506

Maybe I misunderstood the spring kafka documentation, but I assumed it would print : 
`[test, foo] 
[In recoverer, In recoverer] // bar and cheese 
[herp]`

Have I misunderstood and applied Batch incorrectly here?

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, I tried to make easier to read, but did not have much luck :(

Comment: It's a bug, but see my answer about the preferred mechanism for error handling with batch listeners.

Comment: Thanks for the update Gary, I was trying something similar but having to catch the NotRetryableExceptions and throw a BatchListenerFailedException was ok for a few exceptions but as the list of NotRetryableExceptions grow it felt a bit clunky. 

Will the DefaultErrorHandler/ConsumerRecordRecoverer handle this in the future, is the above approach still the preferred mechanism?

My use case was to consume data in a batch, and save all the valid data into the db in a batch statement.

Comment: Yes, it will work in 2.9.3 and 2.8.11 in a few weeks; but the entire batch is sent to the DLT, even if only the first record has a problem. The fix is currently available in 2.8.11-SNAPSHOT and 2.9.3-SNAPSHOT which can be used for testing (but should not be used in production).