# define non retryable exception in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

hi i have a kafka consumer application that uses spring kafka. It is consuming messages batch wise. But before that it was consuming sequentially. When i consume sequentially i used below  annotation

```
  @RetryableTopic(
          attempts = "3}",
          backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 2.0),
          autoCreateTopics = "false",
          topicSuffixingStrategy = TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE,
          exclude = {CustomNonRetryableException.class})
```

In my code i throw CustomNonRetryableException whenever i dont need to retry an exception scenario. For other exceptions it will retry 3 times.
But when i switched to batch processing, i removed above code and used below kafkalistenercontainerfactory.

```
@Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.DEBUG);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setMissingTopicsFatal(false);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH);
    factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate(),
            (r, e) -> {
              return new TopicPartition(r.topic() + "-dlt", r.partition());
            }),new FixedBackOff(1000L, 2L)));
    return factory;
  }
```

Now what i'm trying to do is apply that CustomNonRetryableException class so that it wont retry 3 times. I want only CustomNonRetryableException throwing scenarios to be retried one time and send to the dlt topic. How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug - see this answer [Spring Boot Kafka Batch DefaultErrorHandler addNotRetryableExceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74151506/spring-boot-kafka-batch-defaulterrorhandler-addnotretryableexceptions/74182263#74182263)

It is fixed and will be available in the next release.

Also see the note in that answer about the preferred way to handle errors when using a batch listener, so that only the failed record is retried, instead of the whole batch.

Comment: thank you @Gary. One more thing, what if i want to send a whole batch to a dead letter topic without retrying 3 times even though i have configured to retry 3 times. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: You can't; it's a bug. It will be fixed in the next release, due in a few weeks. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2459 It is currently only available in 2.9.3-SNAPSHOT or 2.8.11-SNAPSHOT which should not be used in production (but it's ok for testing). Or, you can write your own error handler.